# Asynchronous rendering in C# winforms using GDI

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, parallel-processing, gdi

I need to render a large amount of lines. CPU has 4 cores, so to improve performance I decided to render them partially into Bitmaps in different threads. Can I improve performance this way? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Yes, GDI+ is *partially* thread-safe.  There's a lock associated with a bitmap, you can't have two threads draw to the same bitmap.  But having them work on different bitmaps is okay.  It will scream loudly when you get it wrong.

Comment: Thanks. There is one more problem. When I create several threads using ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads, only one core is working. How to use all cores?

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem with Graphics. When i set:

```
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
```

only one core is used for all threads but when i set:

```
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
```

it works fine.